# How to get response from o365 connector card in node js bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to make a bot using microsoft bot framework with node.js for integrating with msteams.

for this i am using o365 connector card. this is my o365 card code

```
let choice = "choice";
        let cardAction2 = new teams.O365ConnectorCardActionCard(session)
            .id("cardAction-2")
            .name("Name of product")
            .inputs([
            new teams.O365ConnectorCardTextInput(session)
                .id("text-1")
                .title("write your problem statement here....")
                .isMultiline(true),
            new teams.O365ConnectorCardMultichoiceInput(session)
                .id("list-3")
                .title("Select category")
                .isMultiSelect(false)
                .style("expanded")
                .choices([
                new teams.O365ConnectorCardMultichoiceInputChoice(session).display("1lt").value("1lt"),
                new teams.O365ConnectorCardMultichoiceInputChoice(session).display("2lt").value("2lt"),
                new teams.O365ConnectorCardMultichoiceInputChoice(session).display("3lt").value("3lt"),
            ]),

        ])
            .actions([
            new teams.O365ConnectorCardHttpPOST(session)
                .id("cardAction-2-btn-1")
                .name("send")
                .body(JSON.stringify({
                text1: "{{text-1.value}}",
                text1: "{{text-3.value}}",


            })),
        ]);

        let card = new teams.O365ConnectorCard(session)
            .summary("o365_card_summary")
            .themeColor("#E67A9E")
            .title("product")
            .text("Please write your problem statement")

            .potentialAction([
            cardAction2,

        ]);
        let msg2 = new teams.TeamsMessage(session)
            .summary("message summary")
            .attachments([card]);
        session.send(msg2).endDialog();
```

now the problem is that i am unable to **get the send button response**.
how can i get the response.when i am trying to click on send button i am getting this error

```
TypeError: this.onInvokeHandler is not a function
```

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you also getting any messages like "There was a problem submitting your changes. Try again in a minute."?

Comment: @BlackSeraph i am getting same message..when clicking on send button

Comment: I solved this issue.... 
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/master/Node/samples/app.js